# passed a vb6 properties class into a c# class constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a class in VB6 that holds a lot of properties for files.
I have converted our Emailer over to C# code.
The VB6 file class will have lots of information that is useful to the Emailer.

So the question arose:
**Is there a way to take the class I have in VB6, and push it to my C# Emailer constructor?**
Is this possible?

In VB6 code, I have linked the DLL to the project with COM interrupt, 
and then in VB6 code I can do something like..

```
Dim fileObj    As New FileProperties
  ...fill out the object...

Dim emailObj   As New Emailer(fileObj)
emailObj.SendEmail()
```

but how would C# know what dataType to accept in the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exposed constructors with parameters to COM.

Ideally your FileProperties class should be in your C# code and exposed through COM along with your Emailer class. Your emailer class would expose a property of type FileProperties, which would get initialized in your parameterless constructor.

In VB6 you would do

```
Dim emailObj As New Emailer
```

and then fill in FileProperties using

```
emailObj.FileProperties.Prop1 = ""
```